# How do I make /dev/sda3 my boot partition?

Tags: boot, partitioning

I have three NTFS partitions as specified below.

```
Device                                                 UUID                     Boot 
/dev/sda1                                             2af4c64ff4c61cc7           * 
/dev/sda2                                             1c58cb9c58cb72d6
/dev/sda3                                             c8ece40bece3f21c
```

When I boot to Ubuntu 12.04 I get the below error

```
Error: no such device  262047AC20478233
Error: File not found
Error: No such disk
Error: You need to load the kernel first

Press any key to continue
```

*262047AC20478233* is referring to a partition from which I have captured Ubuntu using imagex.

By using the 'e' option to edit the commands before booting, I change the UUID to *c8ece40bece3f21c* (/dev/sda3) which has the Ubuntu 12.04 OS ans then it boots up all fine.

How can I change /dev/sda3 as the default boot partition so that I don’t have to edit the UUID manually every time I start my machine.

I am new to Ubuntu. Please advise.

Answer (score 0):

To fix this error you have to type just a Command.

First log on your system. Open terminal by ctrl+alt+t.
Type

```
sudo grub-install /dev/sda3
```

You will asked password, give it. It will install grub on  /dev/sda3. After it you will get message that grub installation successful.

Reboot your system.

Comment: I had tried this earlier. It does say that the installation was successful however when I reboot it still searches for the partition 262047AC20478233. The two lines which I edit in the preboot commands are

Comment: In that case you will need supergrub disk. You can get it from here www.supergrubdisk.org/. Burn the disk and fix your grub boot loader entry.

Comment: I figured out a different command "sudo update-grub -o /boot/grub/grub.cfg" which actually got the grub on sda1 and is now booting from that. However, i couldnt get it booting from sda3. Our organisation doesnt support Live CD deployment so I couldnt do that.